# How can I check if iframe-embedded Youtube video ended?

Tags: javascript, iframe, youtube, event-listener, youtube-iframe-api

I have YouTube videos loading in via Iframe. Is it possible to check if the YouTube video ended when it is in that sort of state? Can I use `OnStateChange()` through Iframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but it's an experimental API:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

Answer (score 4):

you can detect the end of the video like so:

```
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
  if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED){
    // your code to run after video has ended
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have an `iframe` on your page, and its `src` attribute contains a URL which does not have the same domain, protocol or port as the container page, you can not access its `document` because of [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

You may want to look into YouTube supporting [`postMessage()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.postMessage).

If you do own the `iframe`'s contents, then get its `iframe.contentDocument` where you can access the `iframe`'s `document`.