# How to make button visible when the youtube video finishes

Tags: php, html, button

I have a popup on my PHP website with auto-playing YouTube video, I've put a button to <kbd>enter the website</kbd> skipping the popup.

But I want the <kbd>enter the website</kbd> button to be visible only after the youtube video ends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the duration of the video, you can use a `setTimeout()` JavaScript function to show the skip to enter button after that duration.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $(".hidden").removeClass("hidden");
    }, 25000);
});
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/qufb369v/

Comment: the user can pause and play the video so this is not a good one.

Comment: @IdanMagled True... For this we need to make things complicated by adding YouTube API for detecting the pause / play. The intro is not worth this much right?

Answer (score 0):

check this answer: [click me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9900747/iframe-javascript-check-if-youtube-video-ends)

this is the function to check id youtube video has ended (ifram)

```
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
  if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED){
    // your code to run after video has ended
  }
}
```