# How to get info about if video from Iframe has finished?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe

Lets say that our component in react renders typical youtube embeded video

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/kMfFcxcjE_k?rel=0&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

How can I know within the component that renders that iframe about if video has ended or not?

Tried to google but haven't found anything

Answer (score 0):

You can call onStateChange() or check through the reference below :)

https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

Similar question :
[Iframe / Javascript Check if Youtube Video Ends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9900747/iframe-javascript-check-if-youtube-video-ends)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for, https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference .

Instead of directly using iframe, you can use this JS API to control the player. But be aware of deprecations.