# how to enable the button when the youtube video is completed playing only in javascript

Tags: javascript, frontend

in my JavaScript file i have 3 youtube videos , one of this play bases on the customer questions and answers and i have nextButton , i have to disable this button and enable once the video is completed playing below is my snipet of code

```
const video_embeds = [
         // video 1
    '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/jsomething?rel=0&autoplay=1&controls=0" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>',
    // video 2
    '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/asomethingE?rel=0&autoplay=1&controls=0" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>',
    // video 3
    '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/something?rel=0&autoplay=1&controls=0" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>'
]   

    let vidembed = video_embeds[1]
    if (total < cutoffs[0]) {
        course = course_blurbs[0]
        vidembed = video_embeds[0]
    }
    if (total > cutoffs[1]) {
        course = course_blurbs[2]
        vidembed = video_embeds[2]
    }


    let nextButton = document.createElement('button')
    nextButton.classList.add("btn", "btn-primary")
    nextButton.innerText = 'nexButton'              
    nextButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
        window.location.href = 'surveyQuestions'; //change to next page
    })
```

I am new to Javascript. How to solve this one. thanks in advance

Comment: One possibility is to use the [official Youtube-API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) instead of iframe and a link. It would require some reading into but ultimately would give you grater control on how to interact with the youtube-video

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Iframe / Javascript Check if Youtube Video Ends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9900747/iframe-javascript-check-if-youtube-video-ends)

Comment: Not too sure if this what your looking for but look at https://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_event_ended.asp

Comment: Thanks @A-Tech that works out for me.

Comment: @aruna glad to hear. If you want you can add your implementation as an answer to your question, so others can see how to solve it.

Comment: videoElement.addEventListener('load', () => {
  // Simulate 'ended' event using a timeout
  setTimeout(() => {
   console.log('Video ended');
   // Perform actions when the video ends
   enableButton();
  }, 121000); // Timeout duration (milliseconds) 
 });

Comment: Now i have 3 videos based on the condition those will play but the above code is working based on the time , which i have set i want when the video ends it has to cal the fumction. @A-Tech  Do you have any solution?

Comment: How can i convert iframe video's to official Youtube-API

Comment: @aruna [this link](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) directs you to the official documentation by Youtube. There should be a "getting started" section if you scroll a bit, complete with examples.

Comment: Still i didn't get this one because i am very new to Javascript first time implementing the code